# Load random HTML page on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of different html pages, and need one to get randomly loaded on each page refresh. This is what I have so far, the only problem is I get stuck in an infinite refresh loop. How can I have this just load a single page on refresh?

```
  var sites = ['/one.html', '/two.html', '/three.html'];
  var randomUrl = sites[Math.floor(Math.random() * sites.length )];
  window.location.reload = randomUrl;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you perhaps have that script in all three of the HTML pages?

Comment: I do... which makes sense as to why it's stuck in a loop. How would it know to load a random file on refresh if the script isn't loaded on each of them though?

Comment: Do you want to load a single page, and then forward to one of the three random pages, or do you want to forward to a random page whenever you hit one of the three pages?

Comment: I'm building sort of a StumbleUpon (but with local URLs), so I'm not necessarily looking for any forwarding, rather than just to load any of the html pages randomly every time a user refreshes the page. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense. You could make an `index.html` page, load a random file in that using AJAX and inserting its content into DOM. I'm going to write an answer now describing this in more detail.

Comment: window.location.reload does not take a path.....

Comment: Random logic should be handled on the server side. That means whenever a page is requested server rolls the dice and sends a random page.

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure what that means. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @AdityaGupta Is there a simple way to do that with JavaScript? I do not currently have any backend for this.

Comment: reload is a method.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload You do not use it to navigate to a new page!

Comment: There is no way to know if the page was refreshed or navigated to.  You can store session info to see if the page is loaded, but that does not handle cases if user has more than one window open and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just writing a small not production learning page (because it is not good practise in my opinion). You could use a Cookie/[localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)/[sessionstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage#Browserkompatibilit%C3%A4t).

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('loaded')===null){
   sessionStorage.setItem('loaded', '1');
   **YOUR CODE** 
}
else{
   /* remove if you just loaded a random page so it will work after the next reload */
   sessionStorage.removeItem('loaded')
}
```

I will you sessionStore because it will reset if the browser is closed but in fact, it doesn't really matter at this point.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks very much. Just curious, why is this considered bad practice?

Comment: I don't know… it is just feeling. Maybe it´s fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You get an infinite loop because everytime the new page is loaded, the script is executed again and again and also because you have the same script loaded in each one of those html. You could have an event trigger to make it execute only after it happens, for example, a mouse click (example below)
If you wish this random page to open only once, you may put the script only in the main page.

```
document.onclick = reloadpage;

function reloadpage() {
    var sites = ['/one.html', '/two.html', '/three.html'];
    var randomUrl = sites[Math.floor(Math.random() * sites.length )];
    window.open(randomUrl, "_self");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix would be passing a parameter

```
window.location.reload = randomUrl + "?reload=0";
```

and check for reload=0 query param before you do

```
window.location.reload = randomUrl;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Doesn't load any other html page on reload. I'm also somewhat new to javascript so I literally just copy and pasted.